# when I am typing "from pandas import none" in vs code, it is not underlining it as error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I cannot determine why my vs-code is not highlighting wrong import statements. when I import wrong module from a package it's not showing a error, but when i run, it's showing error. Is There a extension or something that can highlight wrong import statements? Need Help!

Comment: AFAIK, pylance does detect modules in the pythonpath

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.